# Is there any point in crafting the same tool multiple times?

Tags: danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc

After beating the main game, I have unlocked *School mode*.
The purpose of *School mode* is to...

> build backups for Monokuma.

I can choose to craft tools, which "*double the number of materials collected*".

So far so good, but I was wondering if the tools' effects stack.
If I craft 2 Microscopes, for instance, will the number of science materials collected quadruple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot craft more than one of the same tool.

However, it is likely that the effects of *Long Mop*<sup>**1**</sup> and *Hi-Tech Mop*<sup>**2**</sup> do stack.

---

<sup>**1**</sup>: "*Raises cleaning efficiency.*"
<sup>**2**</sup>: "*Greatly raises cleaning efficiency.*"